# How to save an image to disk without user interactive?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I see flash has a [`save`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/FileReference.html#save()) call to do this job, but it requires user interactive.

How to save it automatically?

Comment: if i'm the user, i wouldn't want to use your application...

Comment: But it's only used at server side.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no built-in `save` method! what is this supposed to do? Maybe you meant `browseForSave` which is only available in AIR.

Comment: Then how to post an image to save at server side with flash ?

Comment: @Makram There is a [save](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29) method in the `FileReference` class that targets Flash player 10.

Comment: @Amarghosh,isn't it already cited in my post? It just requires user interative.

Comment: Did you notice that I was talking to @Makram who wasn't aware of `save` method (which was not present in Flash 9)?

Comment: And the said save method doesn't do what you think it does - it's for saving file on client's machine, not the server. Try to be nice to the people who're trying to help you - especially if you cannot express your question clearly.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to save the file at the server side. If this image is from the hard disk of the user, then you cannot do it without user interaction. Basically, you can't just steal files from user.

If it is generated using your SWF itself, you can encode the image's `bitmapData` to PNG format and [upload it to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138393/exception-when-trying-to-upload-file-from-flex-to-rails-using-paperclip) using a `URLLoader` and save it to file using your server script.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't, otherwise Flash would be the #1 virus uploader of all time.

Comment: If true most server sides languages should be virus.

Comment: Most server side languages are sandboxed by the browser, but since Flash runs as a system-wide plugin and not solely in the browser it has a more threatening potential.