# Why is the bitmapdata not posted to server side with flash?

Tags: php, flash, http, upload

Here is the code I used to post the bitmapdata to server side(**PHP**):

```
private function savePicToServer(bmpData:BitmapData):void
{
    trace("in savePicToServer");
    trace(bmpData);
    var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85);
    var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(bmpData);

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/test.php");
    request.requestHeaders.push(header);
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    request.data = jpgStream;
    loader.load(request);
    trace("finish savePicToServer");
}
```

Here is the code at server side:

```
file_put_contents('data.txt',var_export($_POST) . var_export($_FILES) . "\r\n" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

But in `data.txt` only this:

```
127.0.0.1
```

Finally the `trace` output is :

```
in savePicToServer
[object BitmapData]
finish savePicToServer
```

What's wrong with my code above?

Comment: Forgot to mention,I'm using `JPGEncoder` in `as3corelib` with the help of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167636/which-package-do-i-need-to-import-to-use-jpgencoder-in-flash

Answer (score -1, accepted):

did you try [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php)?

Comment: Wow, it works! @back2dos, can you explain why `$_POST` and `$_FILES` don't work here?

Comment: @ieplugin: `$_POST` is an array containing all parameters sent per post and `$_FILES` is an array of all files uploaded as such. You would get this using `flash.net.FileReference::upload`. However, in this case, the content is uploaded as plain post content.

Comment: That was [deprecated in PHP 5.6](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.deprecated.php)