# What's the difference between POST and raw POST in PHP at all?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have this question after reading the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169831/why-is-the-bitmapdata-not-posted-to-server-side-with-flash/3170929#3170929), what's the difference at all?

Is it possible to submit raw POST with html ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We can divide form submissions in three cases:

1. Submissions with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
2. Submissions with content type `multipart/form-data`
3. Other submissions.

In cases 1 and 3, `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` contains the raw post data (except if the option is `always_populate_raw_post_data` is set to `false`, in which case `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is empty in case 1), i.e., the data exactly as the client (usually the browser) has sent it. In case, 1, the data has a form such as

```
key1=value1&key2=value2&key3[]=value3.1&key3[]=value3.2
```

PHP automatically parses this, so that `$_POST` becomes:

```
$_POST = array(
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => "value2",
    "key3" => array("value3.1", "value3.2");
)
```

The contents of the raw data can also be access through `php://input`, even in case 1 when `always_populate_raw_post_data` is set to `false`. In particular, `file_get_contents("php://input")` gives the same data `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` has or would have.

In case 3, in which the POST data is arbitrary, `$_POST` will be an empty array and `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` will always be populated.

Case 2 is a special one. In that case, PHP will parse the data and `$_POST` will get the content of the fields which are not uploaded files, but `php://input` and `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` will be unavailable.

Comment: This explanation helped me understand what was going on when jquery calls $.ajax and passes json data to another page.

Comment: As a side note, this applies to things beyond form submissions. I came here looking for an explanation of why I had to parse POST requests from AWS SNS notifications using php://input instead of $_POST and this explained it perfectly.

Comment: `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` was [deprecated in PHP 5.6](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.deprecated.php)

Answer (score 5):

`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` will contain something like:

```
beans=cheese&spam=eggs&one=two
```

PHP splits this up for you, and shoves it in the `$_POST` array. Naively, it does something like this:

```
$parts = explode('&', $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
foreach ( $parts as $part ) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $part, 2);
    $_POST[$key] = $value;
}
```

Using JavaScript, which can be embedded into HTML, you can POST anything you like with [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp). Something like this:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', 'http://www.example.com/my_url' true);
req.send('any data you want');
```

will allow you to POST arbitrary things to the web server.

Comment: Your example code should do `urldecode()` on `$key` and `$value`.
This assumes `<form enctype>` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is the default for most HTML forms. There is also the `multipart/form-data` which is used for file uploads.

Comment: I left out some details for clarity, hence me saying "naively".

Answer (score 0):

[`_POST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) assumes it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` form values.  [`HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php), if populated, is the raw string.  You can also access this with the psuedo-url [`php://input`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).  You can submit arbitrary POST data (e.g. XML, JSON, HTML) using AJAX.

Comment: $_POST also contains the parsed data when the content type is multipart/form-data, in which case `php://input` cannot be used (same for HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is an associative array of the incoming POST parameters. PHP creates this for you from the raw HTTP post. If you want to deal with the raw POST data yourself (you might have some binary data sent in the POST), use $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA.