# Differences between HTTP Raw Post Data and just Post data

Tags: php, ruby, http, post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between POST and raw POST in PHP at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173547/whats-the-difference-between-post-and-raw-post-in-php-at-all)

I know about how capturing them on php and on ruby.

But i wonder, what is difference? why these two came with different params?

or i should ask like this when the raw post data come and is it about with my server-side scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"raw" post data is un parsed. It is just a string that needs to be parsed into individual key value pairs, and urldecoded.

$_POST however has all of this already done for you. It's not often one would prefer the raw post data.