# $_POST vs. $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA vs file_get_contents(php://input)?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between POST and raw POST in PHP at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173547/whats-the-difference-between-post-and-raw-post-in-php-at-all)

For a better understanding, I would be grateful if you would explain what are the fundamental differences between **$_POST**, **$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA** and **file_get_contents(php://input)**.

When to use which, and why?

Comment: Have you looked at the manual? What's unclear specifically?

Comment: I belive that 90% of the php programmers user $_POST variable in order to get their posted data. I am working at a project where I have to process a response from a service provider and with $_POST I couldn't reach that piece of data. I don't know exactly why, and I want a clear view over this. I took a look at the manual but still don't have a good understanding.

Comment: I will go through the link you suggested, mario.

Comment: hi michael, that looks like a question from a test?  Is it?

Comment: If you are having trouble accessing data try using [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to see what values are there.

Comment: As PeeHaa said, but also look at `var_dump($_SERVER);` then to see the type of POST paylod by inspecting `CONTENT_TYPE`.

Comment: PeeHaa, Thank you! I am familiar with var dumping and debugging in general. I also have Zend_Debug methods in this particular framework. What I want is a fundamental understanding.

Comment: @mario, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173547/whats-the-difference-between-post-and-raw-post-in-php-at-all) cleared things up. Thank you! Sorry for missing it!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. **$_POST** contains URL encoded *(application/www-url-encoded)* variables that are posted to your script and PHP decodes them for you. You use this one when you deal with **HTML FORM** data.
2. **file_get_contents("php://input")** - gets the raw POST data and you need to use this when you write APIs and need **XML/JSON/... input** that cannot be decoded to $_POST by PHP.
3. **$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA** - in theory it is the same as the above but depends on **php.ini**. **(DEPRECATED, SEE COMMENT)**

I always use method #2 instead of #3 when I need non **application/www-url-encoded** input.

Comment: `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` was [deprecated in PHP 5.6](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.deprecated.php)