# Variables outside if ISSET cannot be accessed inside the if ISSET statement

Tags: php, variables, global-variables, scope, isset

I have this code:

```
function WriteLog($offer,$values) {
    $Filename = "./".$offer.date('Ymd').".txt";
    $fh = fopen($Filename, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    $filecontent = $values;
    $filecontent .= PHP_EOL;
    fwrite($fh,$filecontent);
    fclose($fh);
}

$aff = "100";

if (isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
    echo $aff;

    WriteLog('events',$aff);

}
```

Here's the problem: The `$aff` variable is not accessible. Echoing the `$aff` inside the `if ISSET` statement doesn't display the value of the `$aff`. What's probably causing this? How can I access the value of the `$aff` variable? Note that the `WriteLog()` function was executed but the `$aff` doesn't have a value. Please help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12997460/1699833

Comment: Are you sure that `WriteLog` is executed in this part of the script? Because there seems nothing wrong with it if `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is set.

Comment: Plain and simple: this should work just fine. There's no issue whatsoever with the `$aff` variable. It's not possible for the code to behave as you decribe. You have some other problem in your actual code.

Comment: Yes, the WriteLog was executed. It created a log file but it was empty.

Comment: I suggest you debug it with `die` or something like that, to check, at what part, your code breaks, because your problem is clearly **not** at the piece of script you are showing. As I said, the `WriteLog` probably is executed at a different part then the one you are looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just an idea to check the value of $aff wether it goes inside if check or not.

```
 $aff = "100";

 if (isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
    var_dump($aff);
    WriteLog('events',$aff);
 }
 else{
    var_dump($aff); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` contains the raw POST data.

in your case `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` doesn't contain any value, so your `if` condition failed and not print the `echo $aff;` value.

```
$aff = "100";

if (isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
  echo $aff;

  WriteLog('events',$aff);
 }else{
   echo "HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA not set";
}
```

Comment: OP wrote that WriteLog was executed, so `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` should be set.

Comment: The $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA contains a value. That's why the WriteLog() function was executed. But I'm wondering why the $aff did not contain a value.

Answer (score 0):

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA [requires an ini value to be set](http://in.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data), using the input stream should work without any special ini settings and is also the 'prefered' method.

you need to use an alternative method

```
$postData = file_get_contents('php://input')
```

[the documentation is here](http://in.php.net/wrappers.php)