# Can't send content of Javascript Console Log to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a program which should send a JSON from the Console to a PHP

```
var nice = any_jsonfile;
console.log(JSON.stringify(nice)); // here it shows desired contents
var nice2 = JSON.stringify(nice);
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/postgetter.php",
                data: nice2,
                dataType: "text"
        });
```

The Postgetter contains

```
<?php


$data = $_POST;

$data_string=implode ( $data );


 $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
 $txt = $data_string;
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($data);
 echo "</pre>";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 fclose($myfile);

 ?>
```

I see the ajax is sending it but it doesn't get any data in to the postgetter.php

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I tried this but also not working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript?rq=1

Comment: Is `postgetter.php` in the same directory? If so use `postgetter.php` and not `/postgetter.php`. The `/` might be sending it back to the root folder and depending on how your files are set up, that may not be what you want.

Comment: postgetter.php is in the root, thats right

Comment: What happens if you do `die(var_dump($_POST));` on `postgetter.php`?

Comment: undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it with:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12997460/2460773

sometimes $_POST global will be empty, depending on the type of data sent.
in that case you could use **file_get_contents** to get the raw POST data.

Comment: what, please explain further.?

Comment: gives me undefined=&undefined= a lot